# How to enable and change Symbol levels programmatically?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a vectorlayer which contains some features and I'm having problems representing them because they are being overlapped with an incorrect order. They have a field that numerate each feature so it could be easy to do.

I don't know if there's a better way to solve the problem but I wish to change the Symbol Levels and I couldn't find any function related with that in the QgsSymbol Class.

In the following image you can see where's the parameter that I want to change with code.

[image: Symbol Levels]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `Layer Rendering --> Control feature rendering order` in Symbology menu?

Comment: That works too but I don't want to do it manually, I want to code it in Python. I didn't know that way to do it so I'm going to search information about it.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood it.

Comment: @Manu if you could calculate a symbol level value you can store in your data table you could manipulate that instead, which gets used by the map